# Complex numbers, locus

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

Prove that if $|z-1-i|=1$, then the locus of a point represented by the complex number $5(z-i)-6$ is a circle with center $(-1,0)$ and radius $5$.

I am not able to get the center coordinates though the radius is quite obvious. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You have
$$
5(z-i)-6 = 5(z-i-1)+5-6=5(z-i-1)-1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $w=5(z-i)-6=5(z-1-i)-1 \iff w+1=5(z-1-i)\,$, so $|w-(-1)|=\ldots$

Comment: Thank you, I was messing up with w+1.